# Performance cost/gain of F# Event.Filter

Tags: events, f#

Writing a F# Windows Forms application I discovered the Event.Filter function of F# and I'd like to learn more about it.
What I've done is to convert my existing code :

```
MyControl.MouseMove.Add( fun args ->
    if (args.Button = MouseButton.Left && args.X > 10 && args.Y > 10)
    then // do something
```

to :

```
MyControl.MouseMove
|> Event.filter ( fun args -> 
    (args.Button = MouseButtons.Left && args.X > 10 && args.Y > 10))
|> Event.add ( // do something)
```

I've found the Event.Filter solution really elegant, so I'd like to know if it is only a sort of syntactic sugar or which are the differences of how things work "under the hood".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/control.fs#L2385-2389), you can see that your two code samples do almost precisely the same thing. The only additional overhead is the creation of an extra `Event` by `filter`.

Not using `filter` due to performance would be an excessive optimization, in my view.

Comment: ok nice, I suspected that it was more or less implemented in this way, but I hoped for a more complex mechanism. I agree with you, in fact the use of Event.filter function is more readable and immediate.